# How to show scaled featured image in template?

Tags: templates, post-thumbnails

I need to show the post featured image at the desired position on my theme template. At the same time, I need its width to be 300px and the height- adaptive.

What code should I add to my template?

Comment: If you want the width of the image to be fixed and the height to change you should look into creating a div and adding your image as a cover in the background, otherwise you will be deforming your image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom size image with [`add_image_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) in the functions.php

```
function add_custom_size_images() {
    // Add image size width 300 with unlimited height.
    add_image_size( 'featured-image-300', 300 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_custom_size_images' );
```

And in the template to get the size that you created with [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/)

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'featured-image-300' );
```

**Notice:** If you want it to work with the old images that you uploaded already you need to regenarate the thumbnails. There are some plugins for this.

Plugin for example https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Answer (score 0):

f you want the width of the image to be fixed and the height to change you should look into creating a div and adding your image as a cover in the background, otherwise you will be deforming your image.

Here is the code. You can also see it working here https://codepen.io/guillermo-carone/pen/zLKQON

```
<style>
.post_snap {
    width: 300px;
    height: 75vh;
}
</style>

<div class="post_snap" style="background: url(http://mirlostudio.com/mission-3/wp-content/uploads/sites/28/2016/07/Look-Up-Architecture-17.jpg) no-repeat center; background-size: cover;">
```